# Variable notation when running python commands with arguments in a bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script which is running a bunch of python script all with arguments. In order to have a clean code, I wanted to use variables along the scripts

```sh
#!/bin/bash
START=0
SCRIPT_PATH="/opt/scripts/"
IP="192.168.1.111"

if [ "$START" = "0" ]; then
    printf "%s: Starting\n" "$DATE_TIME"

    PORT=1234
    TEST_FILE="$SCRIPT_PATH/Test Scripts/test.TXT"
    SCRIPT="$SCRIPT_PATH/script1.py"
    ARGS="-P $SCRIPT_PATH/script2.py -n 15 -p $PORT -i $IP"

    python "$SCRIPT" ${ARGS} -f "${TEST_FILE}" > ./out.log 2>&1 &

fi
```

This code is actually working but few things I don't understand :

1. Why, if I add quotes around **${ARGS}**, the arguments are not parsed correctly by python ? What would be the best way to write this ?
2. What is the best method to add `-f "${TEST_FILE}"` to the `ARGS` variable without python blocking on the whitespace and throwing the error: `"$SCRIPT_PATH/Test " not found`

Comment: I'm too lazy to write up an answer, but shell arrays might be interesting here, with the `"${foo[@]}"` expansion syntax. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays .

Comment: @TurePålsson I've already tried that, with no success. The quoted parameters in arrays get parsed either too soon or too late, and I cannot make it so they get parsed when running the command, instead of before entering the array or leaking the quotes to the Python command.

Comment: @TurePålsson Indeed, I tried too and it was failing like Marc is saying

Comment: @RobertJones : The quotes are interpreted by your shell, and just take care that Python receives the variable `ARGS` as a single argument. BTW, your `ARGS` is not an array. Maybe it would be a good idea to turn it into one. However, since you did not specify, what parameters your Python program are expected to receive, it is difficult to give a recommendation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you wrap quotes around an argument list, the argument vector receives a single argument with everything that is wrapped in quotes and so, the argument parser fails to do its job properly and you have your issue.

Regarding your second question, it is not easy to embed the quotes into the array, because the quotes will be parsed before being stored in the array, and then when you perform the array expansion to run the command, they will be missing and fail. I have tried this several times with no success.

An alternative approach would mean that you modify a little your script to use a custom internal field separator (IFS) to manually tell what should be considered an argument and what not:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
START=0
SCRIPT_PATH="/opt/scripts/"
IP="192.168.1.111"

if [ "$START" = "0" ]; then
    printf "%s: Starting\n" "$DATE_TIME"

    PORT=1234
    TEST_FILE="$SCRIPT_PATH/Test Scripts/test.TXT"
    SCRIPT="$SCRIPT_PATH/script1.py"
    OLD_IFS=$IFS
    IFS=';'
    ARGS="$SCRIPT;-P;$SCRIPT_PATH/script2.py;-n;15;-p;$PORT;-i;$IP;-f;$TEST_FILE"
    python ${ARGS} > ./out.log 2>&1 &
    IFS=$OLD_IFS
fi
```

As you can see, I replace the spaces in ARGS with semicolons. This way, `TEST_FILE` variable contents will be considered as a single argument for bash and will be properly populated in argument vector. I'm also moving the script to the argument vector for simplicity, otherwise, Python will not get the proper script path and fail, due to this modification we did to IFS.

Comment: Thank you for this answer ,that's a very clear and this approach is more complicated than what I expected but I have exactly the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking something like this (with some cruft edited out to make it a standalone example):

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_PATH="/opt/scripts/"
IP="192.168.1.111"

PORT=1234
TEST_FILE="$SCRIPT_PATH/Test Scripts/test.TXT"
SCRIPT="$SCRIPT_PATH/script1.py"
set -a ARGS
ARGS=(-P "$SCRIPT_PATH/script2.py" -n 15 -p "$PORT" -i "$IP")
ARGS+=(-f "${TEST_FILE}")

python3 -c "import sys; print(*enumerate(sys.argv), sep='\n')" "${ARGS[@]}"
```